# Filter Excel table matching two columns values

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have an excel table I want to filter only the rows in which the value of the numeric column "customLabel" matches with one of the rows of another column in another google sheet.

Can I use the advanced filter function or should I write a custom function?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is likely to get downvoted unless you [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1373848/edit) to show us sample data, expected outcome and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Without really seeing what you are looking at. If both brought into the spreadsheet (assuming this isn't an ongoing changing item) you could use conditional formatting asking Excel to highlight the duplicate values then using auto filter filter by colour.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to filter your first sheet for only values that are found in your second sheet?

If that is the case, I would a create a new column in your first sheet, and enter a formula like:

> "=COUNTIF(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!A2)"

The first argument points to your second sheet, and the second argument points to the first ID in your first sheet. Drag down the length of the column as far as you need. 
After this, you can filter your new column to exclude the zero value.

Just change the cells in the above formula to point to where you want in the workbook.

Comment: Hello, basically I have an excel sheet with various columns and another excel sheet with one column containing some IDs, I want to filter the first sheet using the values in the column in the second sheet to get just the rows containing those IDs. The values are numeric IDs.

Comment: Hi, I may be misunderstanding your request, but it sounds like you want to filter your first sheet for only values that are found in your second sheet?
If that is the case, I would a create a new column in your first sheet, and enter a formula like "=COUNTIF(Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!A2)" - The first argument points to your second sheet, and the second argument points to the first ID in your first sheet - Then drag down. After this, you can filter your new column to exclude the zero value.
Does that sound close to what you're trying to do?

Comment: thank you, I found the solution yesterday and it was exactly what you wrote :) I used the COUNTIF function!

Comment: No worries! I'll update my answer for any future users encountering the same problem.